# Using ArcGIS field calulator with VB Script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript

My code looks like the following:

```
if [LWS50yrp] <136.5 then    
     [DMG_50y] = 0.1    
elseif [LWS50yrp] >=136.5<154 then
     [DMG_50y] = 0.15
elseif [LWS50yrp] >=154<166 then

...

elseif [LWS50yrp] >=400<500 then
     [DMG_50y] = 1.8
elseif [LWS50yrp] >500 then
     [DMG_50y] = 2
end if
```

Calculation runs all fine. However all values from [LWS50yrp] exceeding 136.5 are assigned to a value of 0.15!

I can't find the mistake, must be a small twist, but I'm only a beginner and have no clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if statements are wrong for this case.

You can visualize how VB is evaluating your statement like this:

```
if [LWS50yrp] >= (136.5   < 154)
```

so that line will catch all values over 136.5 because 136.5 is less than 154

make your statements read this way:

```
ElseIf ([LWS50yrp] >= 136.5) And ([LWS50yrp] < 154) Then
```

- parenthesis were added for readability and may be retained but are not required in this case